# I can't load my files using %PUBLIC_URL% in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm-scripts

even though I reinstalled my react scripts I showing same in the inspect that these files are not loaded but the favicon from the react is loading fine why this happening I have spent 2 hrs and still no uses

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `%PUBLIC_URL%` is [replaced during the build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) with the value you have provided in your settings. Try to run `npm run build` and inspect the `build/` directory created by it.